# Replace a character to another one in a text file using Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that will replace every character `.` to `/` in my `test.txt`. However, something is wrong and my `outfile.txt` is generated empty.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\acaproni\Desktop"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\acaproni\Desktop"
SET "filename=%sourcedir%\test.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 SET "line=!line:.=/!"
 ECHO !line!
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Try `type "%filename1%"&pause` just before `GOTO :EOF` to ensure that input file isn't empty. The script should work.

Comment: Might want to put a space in between your options. `"usebackq delims="`

Comment: Hmm...something oddly familiar about that code...if the input file exists and you have permission to write the output file (which seems reasonable) then the file should be correctly processed, given that it doesn't contain `!`. The `.txt` file wouldn't be actually named `....txt.txt` would it? And are you sure it's straight ASCII text, not unicode and doesn't contain a control-z before the text?

Comment: I suspect it does not find `test.txt` can you `echo %filename1%` and make sure that is the same path as to where `test.txt` actually exists?

Comment: I've tried all suggestions, but unfortunately I couldn't resolve my problem. :/